# std::map object destructor getting called?

Tags: c++

I have a global map object which contains an ID and a class object, but I don't understand why the destructor for the objects in the map are getting called.

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
class TestMapObject{

private:
    std::string m_sName;
public:
    TestMapObject(const std::string& sName){
        std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
        m_sName = sName;
    }
    ~TestMapObject(){
        std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    const std::string& GetName(){
        return m_sName;
    }
};

namespace Test{

    enum ETestMapKeyId{
      k_ETestMapKeyNone = 0,
        k_ETestMapKeyFirst,
        k_ETestMapKeySecond,
    };

    std::map<ETestMapKeyId, TestMapObject> g_tMap;

    TestMapObject* GetMapObjectById(ETestMapKeyId eID){
        auto itFound = g_tMap.find(eID);
        
        assert(itFound != g_tMap.end());
        
        return &itFound->second;
    }
}



int main(){
    Test::g_tMap.insert(std::pair<Test::ETestMapKeyId,TestMapObject>(Test::k_ETestMapKeyFirst,TestMapObject("Alice")));
    Test::g_tMap.insert(std::pair<Test::ETestMapKeyId,TestMapObject>(Test::k_ETestMapKeySecond,TestMapObject("Mocha")));
    //destructor gets called here
    std::cout << " are we destructed? " << std::endl;
    
    TestMapObject* tmKeyFirst = Test::GetMapObjectById(Test::k_ETestMapKeyFirst);
    TestMapObject* tmKeySecond = Test::GetMapObjectById(Test::k_ETestMapKeySecond);
    
    
    
    for(;;){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << tmKeyFirst->GetName() << std::endl ;
        std::cout << tmKeySecond->GetName() << std::endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm able to retrieve a pointer to the objects with GetMapObjectById and continuously able to print their name (Which might be undefined behavior considering their destructor was called). But I'm unsure why the destructor gets called before the application ends..

Output

```
Constructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Constructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
 are we destructed? 

---continues loop print
Alice
Mocha
```

Comment: please include the output in the quesiton

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I added the output.

Comment: `std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;` -- Output the value of `this`, not just a message.  Then do the same thing in the constructor.  You will then see that `this` is not the same object you constructed.  Then the question becomes "what are these objects that I never created doing here?", with the answer as a duplicate link, or one or more answers given below.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah, I see what you mean. The pointers are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is not the `std::map` getting destroyed, but the temporaries you are using to insert elements in the map. You can use emplace to avoid the construction (and destruction) of that temporaries:

```
Test::g_tMap.emplace(Test::k_ETestMapKeyFirst,"Alice");
Test::g_tMap.emplace(Test::k_ETestMapKeySecond,"Mocha");
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a6Pc8d53K)

Comment: I don't understand why calling insert in the map would result in the temporaries getting destroyed. What is the difference here using emplace.

Comment: And thank you, I'll use emplace instead.

Comment: @Kayle `TestMapObject("Alice")` creates a temporary and the element in the map is a copy of that. `emplace` creates the element directly in the map. I have to admit that I don't yet understand why there are two objects getting destroyed, but anyhow with `emplace` its down to `0`

Comment: Ah okay I understand now. So with insert, it uses a temporary object that was created on the stack. Where as emplace actually creates a separate object for the map container itself.

Comment: @Kayla see the `Live Demo` at the end of the answer. Did you change something? Maybe your code looks a little different. You can call also `emplace` with a temporary. The right way is to pass parameters for the constructors

Comment: @Kayla I am not passing a `std::pair` to `emplace`. As I wrote, also `emplace` can be called with a temporary, but when you pass parameters for the constructors (as in my code) then there are no temporaries

Comment: I think I see the problem. You just passed the arguments for the object into the second portion of the map rather than creating an object and then passing arguments? Is that how I should be doing it?

Comment: But what if I have multiple arguments in the constructor? How would that work?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number there are two destructions because there's the conversion from `std::pair<Test::ETestMapKeyId,TestMapObject>` to `std::pair<const Test::ETestMapKeyId,TestMapObject>` in the parameters of `insert`

Comment: @Caleth that was my understanding but calling insert with a pair with `const` key calls the destructor twice as well https://godbolt.org/z/dveK75has

Comment: @Kayla "Is that how I should be doing it?" yes exactly. `std::map::emplace` only came with C++11, before that you had to make a copy. The main purpose of `emplace` is to forward parameters to the constructors, but you can also use it like `insert` and pass an instance of the element type, then the copy constructor will be used